# Save data async

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to store the values from 2 text inputs in my phone and use the data after.

I'm trying to save the data but there is only one character stored... can someone explain to me why please?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import  {
TouchableHighlight,
TouchableOpacity,
AsyncStorage,
AppRegistry,
StyleSheet,
Navigator,
TextInput,
ListView,
onPress,
Button,
Image,
Text,
View,
} from 'react-native';

var styles = require('../style.js');

class config extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = { local: 'test',
                ext: 'test_ext',
              };
 }

componentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("myKey").then((value) => {
        this.setState({"myKey": value});
    }).done();
}

getInitialState() {
   return { };}

saveData(value) {
   AsyncStorage.setItem("myKey", value);
   this.setState({"myKey": value});
}

render(){
//  console.log({IP_LOCAL});
return(

  <View>

  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image source={require('../../img/mob.png')} style={styles.mob_logo}/>
  </View>

    <View style={{marginTop:100}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>Hello From config component</Text>
      <Text>id: {this.props.id}</Text>
      <Text>name: {this.props.name}</Text>
      <Text>name: {this.props.myVar}</Text>

      <Text style={styles.saved}>
          {this.state.myKey}
      </Text>
        <Text> </Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={(local) => this.saveData(local)}
        value=""
      />
    </View>
    </View>
)
 }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: two text input in what sense?

Comment: i have 2 textinput and i want to save ip inside and use them after

Answer (score 0):

i fix with

```
 componentWillMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("local").then((value) => {
        this.setState({"local": value});
    }).done();
    AsyncStorage.getItem("ext").then((value) => {
        this.setState({"ext": value});
    }).done();


}

getInitialState() {
   return { };
 }

 saveData(target, value, i) {
  if (i === 1){
    AsyncStorage.setItem("local", value);
     this.setState({local: value});
  }
   else{
       AsyncStorage.setItem("ext", value);
       this.setState({ext: value});
   }
 }
```

and it's now working

Answer (score 0):

ok i think you should do this:

```
var count;//declare global variable

saveData(value) {
    count++;
   AsyncStorage.setItem(""myKey"+count", value);//you can store distinct //key
   this.setState({"myKey": value});
}
```

Comment: i use   your solution and this one and it's fail     `saveData(target, value, i) {
      if (i === 1){
        AsyncStorage.setItem("local", value);
         this.setState({local: value});
      }
       else{
           AsyncStorage.setItem("ext", value);
           this.setState({ext: value});
       }
   }`